# Python 3.6 import requests

Tags: python, import, python-3.6

Hi im pretty new to python and im following some tutorials online.
im using the latest version of python 3.6 when i try and import requests or bs4 is says

ModuleNotFoundError, No module named 'requests'

although it is installed i can see it in site packages i used pip to install whatever i seem to do it doesnt seem to be able to find it

here is the code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import operator


def start(url):
    word_list = []
    source_code = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code)
    for post_text in soup.findAll('div'):
        content = post_text.string
        words = content.lower().split()
        for each_word in words:
            print(each_word)
            word_list.append(each_word)

start('http://localhost/budget_app/dashboard.php')
```

this is the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError, No module named 'requests'
```

Comment: Are you sure the pip you are using corresponds to the Python interpreter you are using? Do you have other installs of different versions of Python on your system?

Comment: Do you see it in the list when you do a ``pip freeze``. You might have several python versions installed. What operating system are you using?

Comment: If on Windows, run `py -3.6 -m pip freeze` in a console to *make sure* that you are running pip with 3.6 and that you get the list of packages installed for 3.6.  Otherwise, replace `py -3.6` with whatever you need to make sure which python you are running.

Comment: astroid==1.5.2
colorama==0.3.9
isort==4.2.5
lazy-object-proxy==1.2.2
mccabe==0.6.1
pylint==1.7.1
six==1.10.0
virtualenv==15.1.0
wrapt==1.10.10  this is what i get when i use pip freeze so it doesnt seem to install it.. when i look in C:\Program Files\Python36\Lib\site-packages it shows it there

Comment: im not sure how i would have separate interpreters i only installed python the once a few days back

Answer (score 6):

Run following command on your virtual environment:

```
sudo pip install requests
```

Answer (score 3):

Run following command if you have more than one python3.x

```
python3.6 -m pip install requests
```

Answer (score 2):

If your facing issue with proxy setting then run below command:

```
pip install requests --proxy http://<username>:password<password>@<IP>:<port>

--proxy     [user:passwd@]proxy.server:port.
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. Despite having the requests packages appeared as installed when I would run the `pip install requests` and the `pip3 install requests`. The package would also show as present when running the pip freeze command.

I used the file explorer window to find the location of the library and manually copy and paste the package files from the `site-package` folder and into it parent `Lib` directory.

I hope this helps.